# Logging DEBUG logs are not shown when executing the Python Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure, logging, azure-functions

I have created a Python Azure Functions app. In this application I want to check log details like `DEBUG`, `INFO` etc. I have written some code for logging purpose, but I am not able to get any log after executing my azure function application.

I have written basic code for logging purpose as below but after executing Azure Functions I am not able to see the log on console.

```py
    import logging
    import azure.functions as func

    data = "Hello"
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.debug(data)
```

Is there any other solution or workaround for the above problem?

Comment: Probably azure is messing with the level of the root logger. Use `logger = logging.getLogger(name)` to get a different logger and use that one.

Comment: @blues I tried `logger = logging.getLogger(name)` but not getting any result can you  please help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely the root logger got messed with by azure and `basicConfig` only creates a root logger with some sane defaults. To work around this create your own independent logger.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('akshay')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
sh = logging.StreamHandler()
sh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(sh)
logger.debug('Hello')
# Outputs 'Hello'
```

Comment: For some reason they do not recommend doing this in the Azure documentation itself, which is too bad since this approached was needed for our team to get logging to work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Cazurecli-linux%2Capplication-level#logging

Comment: @BenGoodman You can access the root logger azure uses too if you just need to set the level: `rootlogger = logging.getLogger()` (no argument on getLogger() gives the root) and `rootlogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`

Comment: I think if you do this you lose monitoring of the performance and errors in app insights.

Answer (score 5):

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/248#issuecomment-462944936) explains the solution:

> As for the original issue noted here, the desired behavior can be achieved with a combination of two steps:
>
> 1. Setting the root logger in user code to use the debug level (it is set to to info by default).
> 2. Configuring the host.json to log Debug messages: [...]

Specifically, this is the code that you need in your script:

```
import logging
logging.Logger.root.level = 10
logging.debug("Debug message here")
```

Comment: This is a valid solution! Having`logging.Logger.root.level = 10` in my function code enables full logging control from `host.json`-file. Without level 10, only information-level logging works.